# Resetting redux state for specific items

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have an initialState like the following:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialBannerContentState = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'bg',
        url: '',
        isSet: false,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'logo',
        url: '',
        isSet: false,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
];

const bannerContentSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'bannerContent',
    initialState: initialBannerContentState,
    reducers: {
        updateBannerContent(state, action) {
            const { id, item, value } = action.payload;
            const existing = state.find((item) => item.id === id);
            if (existing) {
                switch (item) {
                    case 'url':
                        existing.url = value;
                        break;
                    .... // and more
                    default:
                }
            }
        },
        resetBannerContent(state, action) {
            const { id, item } = action.payload;
            const existing = state.find((item) => item.id === id);
            if (existing) {
                switch (item) {
                    case 'bg': // item with id 1
                        initialBannerContentState[id];
                        break;
                    .... // and more
                    default:
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

export const BannerContentActions = bannerContentSlice.actions;

export default bannerContentSlice.reducer;
```

Then I am using it like:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { BannerContentActions } from '../../store/bannerContent';

const someThing = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={
            dispatch(BannerContentActions.updateBannerContent({
                id: '1',
                item: 'bg',
                url: 'someimageurl'
            }));
            dispatch(BannerContentActions.updateBannerContent({
                id: '1',
                item: 'isSet',
                url: true
            }));
        }>
            Setting some image url
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={
            dispatch(BannerContentActions.resetBannerContent({
                id: '1',
                item: 'bg'
            }));
        }>
            Resetting initial data id 1
        </Button>
    </div>
);

export default something;
```

So what I am trying to do is to reset everything for id 1 to its initial state.
The update function does work, but the reset doesn't do anything. Nothing is changed on the id object.

So I am not sure where it goes wrong, most likely its some logic, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the `resetBannerContent` reducer case is mutating the state object or returning a new state object value.

I'd suggest searching for the index of the matching element object and mutate the state at that index with the initial state value of the same index.

You also should be dispatching the action within a callback function, not immediately when the button renders, e.g. `onClick={() => dispatch(...)}` instead of `onClick={dispatch(...)}`.

Example:

```js
resetBannerContent(state, action) {
  const { id, name } = action.payload;

  const index = state.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id === id && item.name === name
  );

  if (index !== -1) {
    state[index] = initialBannerContentState[index];
  }
}
```

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch(BannerContentActions.resetBannerContent({
      id: '1',
      name: 'bg'
    }));
  }}
>
  Resetting initial data id 1
</Button>
```

Note: If the `item.id` properties are globally unique you likely don't need to also pass the 'bg' `name` value.

```js
resetBannerContent(state, action) {
  const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload);

  if (index !== -1) {
    state[index] = initialBannerContentState[index];
  }
}
```

```
<Button onClick={() => dispatch(BannerContentActions.resetBannerContent('1'))}>
  Resetting initial data id 1
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks @drew-reese, thats seems logic indeed. Will work on further improvement.